# Why is JDBC a typical application of Bridge design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, jdbc, bridge

I found from lots of resources that JDBC is a typical example of Bridge design pattern. But they usually didn't tell the details, so I would like to know the details. According to my understanding:

- `Driver` interface is the *bridge* between the `DriverManager` and the concrete JDBC driver classes
- `Connection` interface is the *bridge* between the `Driver` and the concrete JDBC connection classes
- `Statement` interface is the *bridge* between the `Connection` and the concrete SQL statement classes
- `ResultSet` interface is the *bridge* between the `Statement` and the concete result set classes

Please modify if the my statements are wrong. Also I guess `DataSource` interface is also a *bridge*, but I can not figure out that is a *bridge* between which classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), as defined by the "Gang of Four", means *decoupling an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently*. In this context, it's not so much about bridging different classes together. Instead, the pattern illustrates the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) where the interface (JDBC API) stays the same, but new implementations (JDBC drivers) can be added and substituted for each other.

What this means is that data access code using JDBC only needs to depend on the API interfaces such as `Connection`, `Statement` or `ResultSet`, instead of caring about the actual database system the application is connected to. JDBC will *bridge* the application to the database that's used in the environment the application is deployed to. For this reason, you can run the same code (using JDBC abstractions) against different RDBMS, and only the JDBC driver (implementation) needs to change.

Added by RUI: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29302

Comment: so based on your statement, none of my statements are right? :)

Comment: I think you're using the word "bridge" in two different ways. E.g. saying that "`Driver` interface is a _bridge_ to concrete JDBC driver classes" is IMO in the spirit of the GoF's definition.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't.

The Bridge pattern requires a concrete implementation of one API that maps to a concrete implementation of another API. It is rarely used: in fact I've used it exactly once in the 20+ years since the GoF book appeared, and I regretted that occasion.

JDBC provides abstract definitions of an API (interfaces) that are implemented by concrete implementations of the *same* API, and that in turn undertake network operations, rather than calling a different API.

However a Type 2 JDBC driver would internally be an example of the Bridge pattern. In this architecture the Java layer talks to a JNI layer which talks to a different C API probably already existing and provided by the vendor. This architecture was transitional and I doubt you will find an example now.

Comment: "concrete implementation of one API that maps to a concrete implementation of another API": I don't think that's how GoF defined Bridge. Your definition seems more like the Adapter pattern. GoF's Bridge is about decoupling the contract from the implementation.

Comment: @MickMnemonic No it isn't, it is about being able to vary the abstraction and the implementation independently. You said so yourself. You can't do that if they have the same interface.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with that. An abstraction _is_ the interface to the implementation.

Comment: You can't vary the JNDI interfaces independently of the implementation classes, as the implementation classes have to implement those interfaces. *Ergo* not a Bridge pattern. See GoF pp151-2, where it is repeatedly stated that it is not inheritance, and that there are two abstract interface hierarchies, not one. RMI for example is not a Bridge, but JNDI Type 2 is, as per my answer.

Comment: I still cannot agree with you after reading pp171-173 of Design Patterns. The Window example there is analogous to JDBC's `Driver` interface and the different driver implementations: `We refer to the relationship between Window and WindowImp as a bridge, because it bridges the abstraction and its implementation, letting them vary independently.` You're correct in that the abstraction/contract can only be changed to be more permissive/general; otherwise the implementations would need to change as well.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Well you're arguing with GoF, not with me. The Window exampel they give seems perfectly clear, and it is *not* the architecture of JNDI. There is a public API and there is an implementation API, and the Bridge pattern bridges them. Pp 171-3 are about Composite in my edition, and there aren't any others.